# Define seasons at month/day level in SQL

Tags: sql, date, calendar, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to group dates into seasons but at `DAY-MONTH` level as below:

```
IFF(DATE BETWEEN 21.03 AND 21.06 THEN SPRING 
    22.06-22.09 = SUMMER
    23.09-21.12 = AUTUMN
    22.12-20.03 = WINTER)
```

I tried concatenation and `between` but not luck with that.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that the dates of astronomical seaons vary every year?

Comment: Yes, this naming convention is for internal purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `case`.  Use strings.  And use proper date formats:

```
(CASE WHEN to_char(DATE, 'MMDD') between '0321' and '0621' then 'SPRING'
      WHEN to_char(DATE, 'MMDD') between '0622' and '0922' then 'SUMMER'
      WHEN to_char(DATE, 'MMDD') between '0923' and '1220' then 'AUTUMN'
      ELSE 'WINTER' 
 END)
```

Answer (score 1):

[IFF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/iff.html) function allows a single condition. Use [CASE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/case.html) instead.

*Exemple:*

```
CASE 
        WHEN to_varchar(DATE,'DDMM') between '2103' and '2006' then 'SPRING'
        WHEN to_varchar(DATE,'DDMM') between '2106' and '2209' then 'SUMMER'
        WHEN to_varchar(DATE,'DDMM') between '2309' and '2012' then 'AUTUMN'
        ELSE                                                        'WINTER' 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below

```
CASE WHEN TO_VARCHAR(date_c,'DD-MM') BETWEEN '21-03' AND '21-06' THEN 'SPRING' END
```